Boot partition not encrypted - kubuntu 24.04 installer warning
I've just tried to install kubuntu 24.04 (LTS) following the "normal" process for encrypting the OS:

/boot/efi on FAT32
/boot on ext4
root / LUKS2 encrypted.

As I didn't want to use an entire drive for this install, I followed the manual installation process, but on confirming the partition settings I was presented with the following confusing error:

While I've heard it's possible to encrypt the /boot partition, I've never done it before, but thinking this was now supported I followed the advice from the prompt and set it to be encrypted (by checking the box). Unfortunately this just resulted in an unbootable system that crashes out at the grub stage (presumably because it doesn't understand how to load a kernel from an encrypted partition)!
Is there now a proper (easy) way to setup an encrypted boot partition? Is this something I should invest time in doing, or will it just further complicate things like kernel updates?
